# Infopath xml extraction?

Tags: java, c#, jaxb, infopath, jaxb2

I have one requirement in which we have to extract the data from the infopath form, which was uploaded by the requester and perform some insertion operation into the database & call the soap APIS. How to extract the data from the infopath form? Could you please help me with it? Is it possible via JAXB or i've to use C#?